# Ensure two SimpleXMLElement Objects are the same

Tags: php, xml

**Example:**

I have two XML files containing the exact same data, structured in a format similar to the XML below. I have converted these two files into SimpleXMLElement Objects. I now want to use PHP to loop through each element and its data in both SimpleXMLElement Objects and compare them to make sure they are the same.

I was looking at the accepted answer at this solution for help but struggling to figure out how to apply it to my own code.
[Compare SimpleXml Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935118/compare-simplexml-object)

The code should be able to compare any two XML files so I cant apply the second solution as the properties will vary across XML files so I can't define them explicitly. Using asXML seems to ignore the attributes which also need to be checked to ensure no changes have been made.

```
<container name="test">
  <typedef name="stringdef">
    <type name="enumeration">
      <enum name="succeeded">
        <value value="5"/>
        <description>
          <text>Test for succeed</text>
        </description>
      </enum>
      <enum name="failed">
        <value value="1"/>
        <description>
          <text>Test for fail</text>
        </description>
      </enum>
    </type>
    <description>
      <text>Enum description</text>
    </description>
  </typedef>
 </container>
```